# Trying to make glue in Unity for VR game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, simulation, game-physics, virtual-reality

I'm trying to make a system gluing that paints the object then the tool touches it then creates a trigger collider so I can apply my joint logic when another object that can be glued enters the trigger.

Here is what I have so far that I thought should work:

```
public class PaintTool : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Color paintColor = Color.red;
    public float paintRadius = 1f;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        Debug.Log(collision.transform.gameObject.tag);
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Wood")
        {
            MeshFilter meshFilter = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
            if (meshFilter == null)
            {
                meshFilter = collision.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshFilter>();
            }

            Renderer renderer = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<Renderer>();
            if (renderer == null)
            {
                renderer = collision.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Renderer>();
            }

            if (meshFilter != null && renderer != null && renderer.sharedMaterial != null)
            {
                Texture2D texture = renderer.material.mainTexture as Texture2D;
                Debug.Log("check 1");
                if (texture != null)
                {
                    Debug.Log("check 2");
                    ContactPoint contact = collision.contacts[0];
                    Vector3 point = contact.point;
                    Vector3 normal = contact.normal;

                    // Use a MeshCollider to perform the raycast
                    MeshCollider meshCollider = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
                    if (meshCollider == null)
                    {
                        meshCollider = collision.gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<MeshCollider>();
                    }

                    RaycastHit hit;
                    if (meshCollider.Raycast(new Ray(point - normal * 1f, normal), out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
                    {
                        Debug.Log("check 3");
                        Vector2 pixelUV = hit.textureCoord;

                        int textureWidth = texture.width;
                        int textureHeight = texture.height;
                        int pixelX = Mathf.FloorToInt(pixelUV.x * textureWidth);
                        int pixelY = Mathf.FloorToInt(pixelUV.y * textureHeight);

                        Bounds paintedAreaBounds = new Bounds(hit.point, Vector3.one * paintRadius * 2);

                        for (int x = pixelX - Mathf.FloorToInt(paintRadius); x < pixelX + Mathf.FloorToInt(paintRadius); x++)
                        {
                            for (int y = pixelY - Mathf.FloorToInt(paintRadius); y < pixelY + Mathf.FloorToInt(paintRadius); y++)
                            {
                                if (x >= 0 && x < textureWidth && y >= 0 && y < textureHeight)
                                {
                                    Color currentColor = texture.GetPixel(x, y);
                                    Color newColor = Color.Lerp(currentColor, paintColor, paintColor.a);
                                    texture.SetPixel(x, y, newColor);

                                    // Expand the bounds to include this pixel
                                    paintedAreaBounds.Encapsulate(new Vector3(x, y, 0));
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        texture.Apply();

                        // Create a trigger collider that matches the painted area
                        BoxCollider triggerCollider = collision.gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
                        triggerCollider.isTrigger = true;
                        triggerCollider.center = paintedAreaBounds.center - collision.gameObject.transform.position;
                        triggerCollider.size = paintedAreaBounds.size;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This runs but doesn't behave as I intended. I need to make the following improvements for it to be actually useable:

- trigger collider is made comically large
- only paints pixels at the original point of contact and cannot be dragged
- takes no consideration of multiple paints of different sections of the painted object which should each have a trigger collider that represents them

Note that when I say paint I'm referring to painting on the glue and I have tried making this as just spawning an object that when collides makes a joint, but due to having to apply a lot of force to make joints not floppy adding to many joints makes objects cursed and the project is a 3d VR project using hdrp in 2021.3.9f1.

Open to alterative methods to go about gluing. Any help is greatly appreciated.

All details above should summarize this section other then I tried giving chat gpt a go at improving this and the poor guy got very confused lol.

Comment: This is a very **ugly** wall of text.

Comment: i know sorry i dont know why that happened but thanks to nisse for fixing it